# Programa usando malloc() duas vezes

Tags: c, memória, alocação

Por que esse programa que faz a divisão de um número em notação decimal, transforma-o em notação binária e imprime na tela o número na sequencia correto (do *bit* mais significativo para o menos significativo) usa `malloc()` duas vezes?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Stack
    int decimal, q, r;
    int counter, i;
    char *binary = NULL;
    char *aux;

    printf("Digite um nÃºmero em base decimal: ");
    scanf("%d", &decimal);

    counter = 1;
    while (decimal >= 2) {
        q = decimal / 2;
        r = decimal - (q * 2);

        // Heap
        aux = (char *) malloc(counter * sizeof(char));
        if (binary != NULL) {
            memcpy(aux, binary, counter-1);
            free(binary);
        }
        binary = aux;

        if (r == 0) {
            binary[counter-1] = 48; //'0';
        } else {
            binary[counter-1] = 49; //'1';
        }

        //printf("resto %d = %d\n", counter, r);
        counter++;
        decimal = q;
    }
    //printf("ultimo quociente = %d\n", q);

    // Heap
    aux = (char *) malloc(counter * sizeof(char));
    if (binary != NULL) {
        memcpy(aux, binary, counter-1);
        free(binary);
    }
    binary = aux;

    if (decimal == 0) {
        binary[counter-1] = 48; //'0';
    } else {
        binary[counter-1] = 49; //'1';
    }

    printf("Resultado em binÃ¡rio = ");
    for (i = counter-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%c", binary[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(binary);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não analisei profundamente mas existe alguma razão para alocar memória dinâmica? Realmente o algoritmo está bem confuso. Provavelmente não precisa fazer tanto. Você que fez? Tem algum requisito que exija que seja feito assim?

Comment: É um código que o meu professor pediu para analisar e estou com duvida nessa parte, a ideia era usar tudo isso de código para pesquisarmos sobre tudo mesmo

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Se o problema é evitar fazer todo cálculo de um dos restos de novo depois que termina o laço, é fácil resolver. O problema é que está parando quando chega no resto 2 e correto é fazer até o resto ser 1. Então uma simples mudança na condição do `while` resolve isto.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int decimal;
    printf("Digite um nÃºmero em base decimal: ");
    scanf("%d", &decimal);
    int counter = 1;
    char *binary = NULL;
    while (decimal >= 1) {
        int q = decimal / 2;
        int r = decimal - (q * 2);
        char *aux = malloc(counter);
        if (binary != NULL) {
            memcpy(aux, binary, counter - 1);
            free(binary);
        }
        binary = aux;
        if (r == 0) binary[counter-1] = '0';
        else binary[counter-1] = '1';
        counter++;
        decimal = q;
    }
    printf("Resultado em binÃ¡rio = ");
    for (int i = counter - 1; i >= 0; i--) printf("%c", binary[i]);
    printf("\n");
    free(binary);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/COtJAP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ehmoutqf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/RepetitionOffsetError.c).

Não analisei outros aspectos.

Answer (score 1):

> por que esse programa *[...]* usa `malloc` duas vezes?

Para números com `N` bits, o ciclo `while` do programa corre `N - 1` vez. Este ciclo não é executado quando `decimal` for `0` ou `1`.

```
while (decimal >= 2) { /* ... */ }
```

Portanto, dentro do ciclo, a alocação feita não é suficiente para guardar a representação binária completa.

Por isso, no fim do ciclo, o programa faz mais uma alocação para o último bit.

Answer (score 1):

Este exercício que te puseram é interessante: entender o código alheio e
eventualmente modificá-lo.
O código do enunciado tem a virtude de: introduzir vários conceitos
(tipos de memória, mallocs, memcpy, etc,) e ter ainda coisas "melhoráveis"

Em complemento à tua pergunta, se fosse eu (mantendo o espírito do mesmo) para além dos melhoramentos referidos anteriormente,

(1) acabava com a memória dinâmica

```
   char binary[32];
```

ou pelo menos alocava tudo de uma vez (tamanho necessário=1+log2(decimal):

```
   binary=malloc((int)(1+log2(decimal)))
```

(2) substituía os

```
   if (r == 0) {
        binary[counter-1] = 48; //'0';
    } else {
        binary[counter-1] = 49; //'1';
    }
```

por

```
    binary[counter-1] = r + '0';
```

---

em resumo...

```
...
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int decimal, q, r, counter;
    char *binary;

    printf("Digite um número em base decimal: ");
    scanf("%d", &decimal);
    binary=malloc((int)(1+log2(decimal)));

    counter = 0;               //from @pmg
    while (decimal > 0) {      //from @Maniero
        q = decimal / 2;
        r = decimal % 2;
        binary[counter] = r + '0';
        counter++;
        decimal = q;
    }

    printf("Resultado em binário = ");
    while (counter--) { putchar(binary[counter]); }
    printf("\n");

    free(binary);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Era bonito ter uma função `decToBin` :)

Comment: outra sugestão ... começar a contar com `0` ... `counter = 0;` e deixar de usar o `counter - 1`, usando apenas `counter`.

Comment: @pmg, certissimo! vou introduzir; (daqui a bocado ficamos sem código :)

Comment: @pmg, as chavetas são por causa se uma jura que fiz para ver se acerto o código awk e perl. E vou-me portar bem: **não** vou pôr `decimal /= 2`... :)

Comment: @JorgeB. sim! ou ao menos um `printf("%b",decimal)`...